# flash player / as 3 : Redirect as3 Output to Chrome's Developer Console?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome

Is it possible to redirect Flash Player's trace output to Chrome's ( or other browsers' ) developer console ?

Comment: This question is easily answered by search engine, have you tried?

Comment: I don't think it is easy. I have tried to find in Google, but in vein.

Comment: Yes it is: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flash+trace+to+chrome+console

Adrian even showed you "one of the google results"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by calling JS from your app, using ExternalInterface.
Then just call js console.log("message");

Here is a sample:

```
ExternalInterface.call("console.log","your text message to console");
```

You can also have a look at http://ripeworks.com/tracing-as3-to-chrome/  one of the google results.

Also more info about calling JS from AS3 and back here  http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/04/calling-actionscript-method-from-javascript/